# How to compress multiple metrics into a single cloud watch alarm using boto3 AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to combine certain number of similar metrics into a **single alarm** in aws cloud watch. For example lets say for data quality monitoring in sagemaker, one among the metrics that are emitted from **data quality monitoring job** is *feature baseline drift distance* for each column so let say I've 600 columns so each column will have this metric. Is there a possible way to compress these metrics into a single cloud watch alarm ?

If not, Is there anyway to send the violation report as message via AWS SNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure exactly on what out come you want when you refer to "compress the metrics into a single alarm." You can look at using [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html)